# .htaccess (AddIcon AddDescription AddAlt) not working on directory .URL files

Tags: htaccess, directory-listing

I have recently learned how to use my `.htaccess` file and a script to rewrite `.URL` shortcuts into functional links in a directory listing:

- [Make .URL shortcuts into functional links within a Directory Listing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107530/make-url-shortcuts-into-functional-links-within-a-directory-listing)

That solution is working well ... but my other `.htaccess` calls to modify the `.URL` items aren't working (unlike all the other file types):

```
AddIcon             http://SoSaysSunny.com/icos/url.ico     .URL
AddDescription      "<I>(web link)</I>"                     .URL
AddAlt              "URL"                                   *.URL
```

Did the rewriting process change the file extension?

Is there some other way to refer to these files?

---

Once I get that problem fixed, I have another:  I begin the filenames of links to web stores with a "$".  How can I specify the files with this naming scheme?

Here's what doesn't work (even with other file types):

```
AddIcon             http://SoSaysSunny.com/icos/cart.ico    $*.URL
AddDescription      "<I>(web store link)</I>"               $*.URL
```

I know it seems like a lot of work to use directory listing but it's crucial to my website organization (to avoid constantly having to update HTML index files).

- [Directory of Problem](http://sosayssunny.com/eclipse/)

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Those directives are part of `mod_autoindex`, are you sure you have that module enabled in your Apache config?

Comment: The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#addicon) gives an example that uses a relative URL.   I'd try `AddIcon /icos/url.ico .URL`

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I don't think it really matters whether you use an absolute or relative URL here. Although an absolute URL would seem unnecessary if these icons are all stored locally. AFAIK, the stated URL is simply used as-is in the generated HTML. ie. As the value of the `src` attribute on the `img` element.

Comment: The format works for all the other file types:  `AddIcon http://SoSaysSunny.com/icos/pdf.ico .pdf`   `AddDescription "<I>(PDF)</I>"  .pdf`   `AddAlt "PDF" *.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but my other `.htaccess` calls to modify the `.URL` items aren't working (unlike all the other file types)

Ah, yes, the "problem" is actually with the mod_rewrite code that sends requests for `.URL` files to your PHP script (that parses the file to get the URL to redirect to). This just needs a minor change: the `NS` flag is required on the `RewriteRule` directive.

The problem stems from the fact that when Apache constructs a directory listing it issues an internal subrequest for each file that is listed. The mod_rewrite code is rewriting this internal subrequest, which it doesn't need to, and preventing the `AddIcon` directive from matching (since the `.url` request is rewritten to a `.php` script). (It only needs to rewrite direct requests from the user.) Based on [my earlier answer to your question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/107575/1243), you probably have something like the following in your `.htaccess` file:

> ```
> # Rewrite requests for ".url" files to our PHP script
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
> RewriteRule .\.url$ process-url-shortcut.php [NC,E=URL_FILE:%{REQUEST_FILENAME},L]
> ```

You just need to add the `NS` (`nosubreq`) flag to the `RewriteRule` in order to prevent the directive being processed for subrequests (ie. so it's only processed for **n**on-**s**ubrequests). For example:

```
RewriteRule .\.url$ process-url-shortcut.php [NS,NC,E=URL_FILE:%{REQUEST_FILENAME},L]
```

> I begin the filenames of links to web stores with a "$". How can I specify the files with this naming scheme?

Ok, this a bit of a weird one. However, this seems to work if you change the wildcard pattern from `$*.URL` to `*$*.URL`, ie. append a `*` to the pattern (as if there were characters before the `$` - but there isn't). So, for example:

> ```
> AddIcon             http://SoSaysSunny.com/icos/cart.ico    *$*.URL
> AddDescription      "<I>(web store link)</I>"               $*.URL
> ```

The `AddDescription` directive still seems to work OK with the `$*.URL` pattern!

> ```
> http://SoSaysSunny.com/icos/cart.ico
> ```

Another potential problem is that you appear to be using [ICO format files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)) for your icons (mime-type: `image/x-icon`). This is primarily a Microsoft Windows file format, so they aren't going to display (correctly) on all OS/devices. eg. These won't display at all on Android/iOS (iPhone/iPad) if that is a concern. It would be preferable to use PNG (or GIF) files instead.

> ...to avoid constantly having to update HTML index files

I agree, no-one want's to manually update an index file every time you upload a file. However, the alternative is to have a (PHP) script that generates your directory listing instead of relying on Apache. Whilst this might be more work in the beginning (unless you have a premade script) - this would potentially give you far greater control and a more portable solution.

---

**UPDATE:**

> ... But the `*$*.URL` modifications still aren't working.

You need to change the order of the directives so that the most specific directives/patterns are first. In other words, you currently have:

> ```
> AddIcon           http://example.com/icos/url.png         .URL
> AddDescription      "<I>(web link)</I>"                     .URL
> AddIcon             http://example.com/icos/cart.png        *$*.URL
> AddDescription      "<I>(web store link)</I>"               $*.URL
> AddAlt          "URL"                           *.URL
> ```

The directives need to be reversed, so that the most specific (ie. `$*.URL`) are first:

```
AddIcon             http://example.com/icos/cart.png        *$*.URL
AddDescription      "<I>(web store link)</I>"               $*.URL
AddIcon             http://example.com/icos/url.png         .URL
AddDescription      "<I>(web link)</I>"                     .URL
AddAlt          "URL"                           *.URL
```

Comment: I added the `NS` flag and that fixed the `.URL` calls.  I've converted the ICOs to PNGs (thanks for the info).  Thanks!   ... But the `*$*.URL` modifications still aren't working.  The current `.htaccess` file is copied to:  http://sosayssunny.com/htaccess.txt

Comment: You need to make sure the most specific directives are first - I've updated my answer.